# Changing NavigationBar and System Colors Without Tint

Tags: swift, ios8, uikit, uinavigationbar

Im trying to change the color of my navigation bar on every view controller of my app, but when I use the line: `UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0xFF0000)` (`UIColorFromHex` is my own custom function that does what it sounds like) in the `AppDelegate.swift` I get a weird gradient that changes from view to view:
[image]
[image]

I want a completely opaque red background, or any color for that matter, app-wide so it looks consistent. Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Navigation bars are translucent by default, you need to turn that off, then use `barTintColor` to change the background of the navigation bar:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Setting the background color changes the semi-gross color *underneath* a translucent bar - you don't need that.

Comment: What do you do about the view misplacement when you do this? With a translucent bar the view goes under, but when you set it to false the view gets shifted down.